# Clase base de mapping de EF a EF Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Por favor, podrian apoyarme en como podria migrar estas 2 clases a EF Core, estoy tratando de usar una clase base para el mapping de mi entidad, hice esto en EF6 pero desearia ver la manera de migrarlo a EF Core

```
Esta es mi clase Base ***BaseEntityMapping*** que utilize en el mapping en EntityFarmework
    
    
  public abstract class BaseEntityMapping<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
            where T : Entity
        {
            private static readonly string PROPERTY_KEY_AUDIT = "IdAudit";
          
            public bool ConfigureAuditMapping(bool isAuditContex)
            {
                var keyAudit = typeof(T).GetProperty(PROPERTY_KEY_AUDIT, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var hasAudit = false;
                if (keyAudit != null)
                {
                    var hasTraceAudit = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<TraceAuditAttribute>();
                    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
                    Expression expr = arg;
                    expr = Expression.Property(expr, keyAudit);
                    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
                    Expression<Func<T, int>> expression = (Expression<Func<T, int>>)lambda;
                    if (isAuditContex && hasTraceAudit != null)
                    {
                        HasKey(expression);
                        Property(expression)
                       .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
                        hasAudit = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HasKey(e => e.Id);
                        Property(u => u.Id)
                           .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
                        Ignore(expression);
                    }
                }
                return hasAudit;
            }
    
Y esta es mi clase de mapping entidad, aqui hago herencia a ***BaseEntityMapping***
    
    public class EmailsMapping : BaseEntityMapping<EmailsEntity>
        {
            public EmailsMapping()
                : base()
            {
                ToTable("Emails", "FNC");
            }
        }
```

Podrian ayudarme por favor sobre esta parte ya que estoy migrando una app de EF a EF Core

Comment: Qué problemas tienes con la migración?

Comment: Me puedes indicar si lo que hace esta clase base de mapping lo hace también Automapper? (la libreria)